# Free batch conversion from FLAC to Apple Looseless (ALAC/m4a)?

Tags: windows, audio, flac, transcode, alac

I am looking for a free tool that would allow me to convert big amounts of FLAC files to Apple Looseless (ALAC) while preserving the tags and optionally adding new ones from CDDB or similar sources.

At this moment I'm more interested in a Windows utility but you are free to recommend OS X ones. Please use different answers for different tools.

Answer (score 1):

For OS X you have [XLD](http://tmkk.pv.land.to/xld/index_e.html).

X Lossless Decoder(XLD) is a tool for Mac OS X that is able to decode/convert/play various 'lossless' audio files. The supported audio files can be split into some tracks with cue sheet when decoding. It works on Mac OS X 10.4 and later.

XLD is Universal Binary, so it runs natively on both Intel Macs and PPC Macs.

XLD can decode following formats:

- (Ogg) FLAC (.flac/.oga)
- Monkey's Audio (.ape)
- Wavpack (.wv)
- TTA (.tta)
- Apple Lossless (.m4a)
- TAK (.tak) [Requires Wine]
- Shorten (.shn) [SHN v3 only]
- AIFF, WAV, etc

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lossless), any media player based on libavcodec should be able to encode ALAC. Such players include [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html), both of which have Windows GUIs available. I'm not sure the Windows GUI for MPlayer exposes any transcoding functionality, but I'm almost certain that VLC's GUI can be used for transcoding.